# Generating "appsecret_proof" for restfb with Scala

Tags: facebook, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, restfb

I am trying to get Facebook user info using `restfb` `1.18.1` with Scala and Play 2.3

for testing I have generated the `Access Token` using `Graph API Explorer` 
now i am using following code to access user info

```
val MY_ACCESS_TOKEN = "abc"
    val  MY_APP_SECRET = "xyz"
    val facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN  ,MY_APP_SECRET )
    val fbuser = facebookClient.fetchObject("me",classOf[User])
    log.info("User first  name :{} ", fbuser.getFirstName)
    log.info("User last name : {}" , fbuser.getLastName)
    log.info("User Email : {}" , fbuser.getEmail)
```

but i am encountering an exception here

```
> play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution
> exception[[FacebookGraphException: Received Facebook error response of
> type GraphMethodException: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API
> argument (code 100, subcode null)]]
```

when i try to make FbClient instance  without MY_APP_SECRET  like this

```
val facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN  )
```

it runs fine and i get info in response from facebook

i have searched but i have not found anything to generate `appsecret_proof` with scala

please guide me

Comment: can you please activate the DEBUG log and send the data that are send to Facebook. Of course you should obfuscate the access token and the app secret proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure your genearted access token for the right application in Graph API Explorer. It was a common mistake for me to generate token for default application selected there. If it's the case your token does not match your secret and this cause the error.

Also if you ask graph explorer for "/me" it'll return you only "id" and "name" as well. If you want additional information specify what exactly you need, for example "/me?fields=id,name,about,age_range"

Comment: Actually you are right i was using access token for  default application .
now that i have selected myApp it is not giving me previous exception but now the problem is that all i am getting from facebook is user name and id,
i am unable to  get public_profile info from facebook which i was able to get using default application in Graph API Explorer
can you please help me with that?

Comment: even now when i enter access token of default application i get all public_profile information for the same user ,  but when i use access token of myApp it just returns me name and id and the logs says " DEBUG - No JSON value present for 'first_name', skipping. JSON is '{"name":"abc def","id":"xyz"}'", same thing for every info related to public_profile

Comment: If you ask graph explorer for "/me" it'll return you id and name as well.  If you want additional information specify what exactly you need, for example "/me?fields=id,name,about,age_range".